# Where to store temporary data (embedded C)

Tags: c, linux, file-io

I have a quite powerful embedded linux device that is to be used for collecting data from various sockets/fd:s using C. This data is to be parsed, buffered and passed on to a TCP/IP or a UDP socket to be transferred somewhere else for long term storage. This last step happens either when a sufficient amount of data has been acquired, or when some other event triggers.

My question is: is there any reason not to buffer everything on the heap (as opposed to writing/reading to some linux file descriptor) given that

- the sole purpose of my device is this type of data acquisition
- the device is never used for long term storage

Using only the heap sounds counter-intuitive, but I can't really see why we shouldn't store as much as we can in the heap, at least until RAM becomes scarce.

Comment: How much RAM do you have? How fast is the data coming in? What's the longest delay before you'll be able to transfer the data to long term storage? At what rate will you be able to transfer the data? Once you have all the parameters of your system, it's just math to determine whether using RAM will work.

Comment: And why using heap is "counter-intuitive"?

Comment: Yes you are right, now I see. You don't need to store the data on the heap at all. Despite any other considerations. Unless, the data is shared for multiple different files that you need to create on the disk, or the data MUST be completely acquired before writing it to the disk. It depends on many things that are not mentioned in your question. Buffering is something that might make sense, but I would need to know all the properties of your system to make a decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite get why you say "using the heap is counter-intuitive" - Millions of embedded routers and switches use the heap for store-and-forward queues (I understand what you do is similar).

It very much depends on the data that you acquire. Anything that can be re-acquired in case of a power failure or other reset events of your device doesn't really need to go into permanent storage.

Data that is hard or impossible to re-acquire and this valuable (like sensor data , for example), you might possibly want to push into a safe place where it is protected from resets and power-down, however.

On the other hand, if your data is not segmented but rather stream-oriented, storing it to a file might be a lot easier - Also beware that out-of-memory conditions and heap memory leaks can be a real nuisance to debug in embedded systems.

Answer (score 0):

Data stored in main memory usually is not retained on power loss. If your collected data must survive power loss, it must be stored in non-volatile memory.

Unfortunately, just writing data to a file does not guarantee reliable storage, sine most linux file systems suffer from risk of data loss on power loss.

A second scenario, where storage in a file might be useful is, that the data collected in a file can survive a crash of your application. We all do our best to never let our applications crash, but despite all efforts, it still happens too often. :-(